# fill a stroke in canvas as progress bar

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

i'm trying to create a progress bar with a unique shape. i know how to fill a shape but i don't know how to fill it with percentages.

i tried using `fillRect` but it's filling the canvas shape without the circle at the end.

this is what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

and this is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to  fill a background rectangle the width of the selected area and the height of your shape's maximum height, then use compositing operations to keep only the part where your shape overlaps, and finally draw the stroke.

```js
slider.oninput = drawGauge;

function drawGauge(evt){
  // first convert the value to our pixel system
  var value = (width / 100) * evt.target.value;
  // clear the previous frame
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw the filled rect the width of our value
  ctx.fillRect(marginLeft, marginTop, value, circleRad*2);
  // change the gCO so we keep only the pixels where our shape and the filled rect overlap
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  drawShape();
  ctx.fill();   // this will make the compositing
 
  // reset the gCO so we can draw the stroke
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.stroke();
  }

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
// the positions of our shapes
var marginLeft = 5,
    marginTop = 5,
    width = 280,
    circleRad = 30,
    circleCenter = width - circleRad,
    rectHeight = 30,
    rectTop = marginTop + (circleRad - rectHeight / 2),
    rectWidth = width - circleRad * 1.82;
// you may have a better version of it ;-)
function drawShape(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(marginLeft, rectTop);
  ctx.lineTo(rectWidth, rectTop);
  ctx.arc(circleCenter+1, rectTop + rectHeight /2, circleRad, -Math.PI*.8, Math.PI*.8);
  ctx.lineTo(marginLeft, rectTop+ rectHeight);
  ctx.closePath();
  }
drawGauge({target:{value:50}});
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slider" from="0" to="100" value="50"/><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```